# how to animate a cylinder unrolling like carpet / toilet paper

Tags: animation

I wish to take a thin rectangle / plane with solidify modifier, roll it into a cylinder and then animate it unrolling. For example, imagine a rolled up carpet or a roll of toilet paper.

The [tutorials](https://youtu.be/4YY7XBpAeWE) I've found so far do not do the rolling / unrolling in a physically correct manner. (The coiling action happens in the center and the outer roll diameter stays the same the whole time.)

Is there a simple and easy way to roll/unroll this cylinder back into a flat rectangle? Currently, it's a rectangle with a curve modifier applied.

[image: Roll side]
[image: Roll angle]

Let me know if there's anything I can add to clarify what I'm looking for.